# getElementById(...) is null ? why?

Tags: javascript, function, methods

Check this code please, and help me solve why i'm getting type error *document.getElementById(...) is null*

```
function Dropdown(){
    this.core = ['NIS', 'EUR', 'USD'];
    this.check = function(){
        var cho = '<select>';
        for(x in this.core){ 
            cho += '<option value="'+ this.core[x] +'">'+ this.core[x] +'</option>';
        }
        cho += '</select>';
        return cho
    };

}

var obj = new Dropdown();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.check();
```

on HTML file i have :

```
  <div id="demo">Check Console log</div>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: this code must be before html is rendered, you can put it after demo html tag, or you can use on window.load method to get that html is rendered

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the document is ready before interacting with it.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var obj = new Dropdown();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.check();
};
```

Comment: i'm always forgot about the page load, i'll just put my <script src=" .. at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call this function when your page rendering then please put the below script before closing `body` tag

```
<script>
// self executing function here
(function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here


function Dropdown(){
    this.core = ['NIS', 'EUR', 'USD'];
    this.check = function(){
        var cho = '<select>';
        for(x in this.core){ 
            cho += '<option value="'+ this.core[x] +'">'+ this.core[x] +'</option>';
        }
        cho += '</select>';
        return cho
    };

}
var obj = new Dropdown();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.check();

})();
</script>
```